# set comparator type expected error

Tags: c++, templates, stl, set

Sorry guys, if this is a stupid question. I have a set of integers which I want be sorted using a function object. But when I try to compile the following code, I get the error "invalid template argument for '_Pr', type expected".

```
    class MySortedUser{
    vector < user* > & users;
    public:
 MySortedUser(vector < user* > & _users):users(_users)
 {
 }
 bool operator()(const int& A, const int& B) const
 {
  return (users[A]->username < users[B]->username);
 } 
   };
    void someFunction(vector < user* > & _users)
    {
      set< int, MySortedUser(_users) > MySet;  //error here
    }
```

Can you please tell me what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MySortedUser(_users)` is an expression (it creates a `MySortedUser` object).  The object is constructed *at run time*.  Templates need to be instantiated *at compile time*.

You need to give `std::set` the type as a template argument and the constructed comparator as a constructor argument:

```
std::set<int, MySortedUser> MySet(MySortedUser(_users));
```